# Get developer keys for Google Cloud Service Accounts

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have enabled the [XML API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/interoperability) and allocated some [Developer Keys](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/migrating#keys) for my own account using the Google Cloud Platform Console.  All working well.

My question is: Is there any way to enable the XML API and get a Developer Key for a Service Account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't. However, if you're willing to complete [a couple additional steps](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/migrating?hl=en_US#migration-full), you can do a full migration and use service accounts natively with minimal effort.

Comment: Thanks @Will. I actually just have an S3 tool I want to use with GCS, but thanks for the pointer.